# GWT popup setGlassEnabled(true) don't work

Tags: gwt, popup

I'm creating a popup panel whit same text, i would like to disable the background and make it grey. I read about setGlassEnabled but it doesn't work, can someone help? ps. the popup is correctly visualized.

```java
PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel(infoType);
popup.center();
popup.setGlassEnabled(true);
popup.show();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The glass panel has no default style, so it's transparent by default. If you want the background to be grayed out, you need to add some CSS styling to the glass panel.

Also, `setGlassEnabled` only enables the glass panel for the *next* time the popup is shown, and in your case, the popup is already showing when you call `show` (because of the previous call to `center`), so it's a no-op and the glass panel actually isn't used. Move your call to `center` to after the call to `setGlassEnabled` and/or call `hide` before `setGlassEnabled`.

Comment: and without the css it don't disable the backgroud?

Answer (score 1):

Putting the following code at the top of your dialog constructor appears to fix the issue for me.

```
setGlassEnabled(true);

Style glassStyle = getGlassElement().getStyle();
glassStyle.setProperty("width", "100%");
glassStyle.setProperty("height", "100%");
glassStyle.setProperty("backgroundColor", "#000");
glassStyle.setProperty("opacity", "0.45");
glassStyle.setProperty("mozOpacity", "0.45");
glassStyle.setProperty("filter", " alpha(opacity=45)");
```

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for setGlassEnabled() is a bit misleading by saying that "the background *will* be blocked with a semi-transparent pane".  In fact all it will do is apply a full-screen div with a default style name of 'gwt-PopupPanelGlass' (as of GWT 2.4, at least).  If, say, your project `<inherits>` a theme such as `com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean`, then clean.css supplies the semi-transparent pane you were expecting:

```
.gwt-PopupPanelGlass {
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
}
```

Otherwise, as previously described, you'll have to roll your own.